# How can I add custom css file in luma theme magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have used Magento 2 with luma Theme. 
I have custom design for theme. I want to add one custom.css file in site.

Answer (score 1):

Create `<your-theme-directory>/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml`

Add the following:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="css/your-css-file.css" />
    </head>
</page>
```

See the dev docs for more info - https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-themes.html

Answer (score 1):

Go to your layout file in

> magento/theme_forntend_luma/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

and add your css file in head section like

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="css/custom.css"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

Then run

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

command to deploy all the static content.

**NOTE: Default.xml is used only when you want to apply your css changes in all the theme.**

Comment: Hi, what is the path of css/custom.css? I tried putting it in vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_Theme/web/css but it didn't work

Comment: for that you have to create child theme on the same dir.

Answer (score 0):

First create your css file for ex. custom.css

put this css at below path

> app/design/frontend/Magento/Luma/web/css

After that specify the path of your css in below file:

> app/design/frontend/Magento/Luma/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml

add following in this file:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="css/custom.css"/>
    </head>
</page>
```