# Adding Custom CSS to Luma theme magento 2.3.0

Tags: magento2, luma-theme

in Magento 2.3.0 I have followed the above solution but still not loading my css, I have search ran all the commands but still nothing. Please any mistake on my implentation below, I am trying to add custom.css to the luma theme.

> app/design/frontend/Magento/Luma/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="css/custom.css"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

> app/design/frontend/Magento/Luma/web/css/custom.css

or

> app/design/frontend/Magento/Luma/Magento_Theme/web/css/custom.css

Comment: In your case follow the below answer and update xml with head tags will get you there. peace :)

Comment: Sorry about that meant to paste the below<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
  <css src="Magento_Theme::css/custom.css" />
    </head>

</page>

Comment: It should not be Magento_Theme it must be as below

Comment: Did that already but doesnt work still

Comment: Magento luma will be vendor folder have you created a theme with the same name so

Comment: Hi I was references an answer on this post:https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/237677/how-can-i-add-custom-css-file-in-luma-theme-magento-2

Answer (score 3):

Adding CSS in Luma theme is not good practice.
Better to create a Custom Theme: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html

And add CSS as below:

1) Adding custom CSS:
add a file under app/design/frontend/VenderName_Theme_name/Magento_Theme/frontend/web/css/custom.css
and add one more file to call that
app/design/frontend/VenderName_Theme_name/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

add below content in the default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>                                             
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../vendor/magento/framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">                                                 
 <head>
  <css src="css/custom.css" />                                   
 </head>                                                         
</page>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Start adding a default_head_blocks.xml file in the module’s view/frontend/layout folder, For custom CSS for a specific layout, we'll start with default_head_block.xml layout. It will apply to all pages in Magento.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <css src="Magenest_CustomCss::css/css-module.css"/>
</head></page>
```